# First primary and then secondary

Tags: cipher

When I was in art school I found an old transcript of a young girl. She used a colour scheme to write down her age and her birthday. But she encrypted it somehow…. Below the (modernised version) of the transcript:

[image]

She added the text: First primary and then secondary.

Can you help me find out what her age is when she made this transcript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:

> There are 26 columns, corresponding to the letters of the alphabet.
>  Reading the primary color (yellow) first, the first row corresponds to 'I';
>  the second row to 'M';
>  then, the secondary color (green), the first row corresponds to 'T';
>  the second row to 'E';
>  the third row to 'N'.
>  This gives: 'I'm ten', so that is her age.

Comment: 26 columns, not rows.

Comment: Yeah, was just writing this up. I thought the green squares might give the date but I guess the year must be 10, so it's probably not this.

Comment: @Randal'Thor thanks *rotates monitor by 90 degrees*

Comment: Oops, made a mistake, therefore the solution for the date wasn't unique.